# Retrieving the serial number of a mapped network drive via FileSystemObject

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a piece of VBA code as shown below

```
VSN = Hex(Format(CDbl(FSO.Drives(FSO.getDriveName(CurrentProject.path)).SerialNumber)))
```

This is where I retrieve the users Volume Serial Number. This works great on local hard drives however, it doesn't on mapped network drives where (i'm guessing) there is no drive prefix (e.g. C: or D:) for the function FSO.getDriveName. It's either that or it fails on FSO.Drives() as it has no drive letter available.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

By the way, the error produced by the code is as follows: Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or arguement.

Thanks in advance for any replies/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to recreate your issue under Access 2010. The code ...

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub DriveSerialNumberTest()
    Dim fso As Object  'FileSystemObject
    Dim VSN As String

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Debug.Print fso.GetDriveName(CurrentProject.Path)

    VSN = Hex(Format(CDbl(fso.GetDrive(fso.GetDriveName(CurrentProject.Path)).SerialNumber)))
    Debug.Print VSN

    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

... returns the following in the Immediate window when the database is opened from a network share via a mapped drive letter ...

```
Z:
DCF1295E
```

... and it returns the following when the database is opened from a network share via a UNC path ...

```
\\Weezer\Public
DCF1295E
```